# Prove that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma=0$ for $ \alpha(x^3 - 2x) + \beta(x^2 + x + 1) + \gamma(x - 2) = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation is: $ \alpha(x^3 - 2x) + \beta(x^2 + x + 1) + \gamma(x - 2) = 
0 $

On the video I'm watching, the teacher says the $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ must be $= 0$ because:

For the coefficient of $x^3$ $\alpha$ there isn't an $x^3$ on the right.

For the coefficient of $x^2$ $\beta$ there isn't an $x^2$ on the right.

For the coefficient of $x$ $-2\alpha + \beta + \gamma$ there isn't an x on the right.

I'm sure this must be pretty basic stuff, but can someone explain to me why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that it has to be equal to zero for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So, the only possibility is that all the coefficients of the polynomial are zero (otherwise you will be able to find a $x$ such that the polynomial is not zero). In your case you have something like $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$
The only possibility for being zero is that
$$a=0,b=0,c=0\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;d=0$$
By imposing this condition you find the solution you were given

Comment: Thank you for the very clear solution!